# Adding a electrical outlet in a closet for wireless router

Tags: electrical, wiring, data-wiring

I want to move my wifi router to a central location in my home. The only ethernet jack is all the way at one end of my house. However I have a hall closet that is centered in the house and would be a perfect location but there is not an outlet in there. On the other side of the closet is the kitchen with an outlet. Can I run wire from that outlet through the attic and back down through the top plate of one of the other walls of the closet. I plan on putting the router fairly high in the closet (about one and half feet from the ceiling) on a shelf and have the outlet right next to it. I have the tools to do the work just not sure if it would be legal.

Comment: What do you plan to do for the ethernet connection?

Comment: Walls block WiFi to a degree.  WiFi router in a closet sounds like the worst idea.

Comment: Drywall and wood are not a major impediment to WiFi or you would need an AP in every room.

Comment: @DaveM, It's not major, but making the permanent home for the radio behind any attenuating material is not a great plan.  Hang it on the wall right outside the closet after you pull electrical and ethernet into the closet, but don't put it behind a door.

Comment: For the ethernet connections I plan on running 4 different lines from the router to different areas of the house. I have a 4 keystone wall plate for the closet and doubles in the 4 rooms.

Comment: Right now the router get almost half signal to the other side of the house going through about 5-6 walls. In the closet it would drop to 1-2.

Comment: you could plug the router's wall wart into the kitchen's outlet, then run the DC output through a small hole into the closet; code doesn't care about DC nearly as much as AC.

Comment: Does that outlet serve a kitchen countertop?

Comment: No it does not. It's just a wall outlet that shares a wall with the dinning room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's legal to power an outlet that's not in the kitchen off of one of the 2 required kitchen branch circuits (i.e. counter outlets). I think it would be OK to tap off of the un-switched side of a light circuit for the kitchen.

Since you have access through the attic, is there another general purpose branch circuit (that is non-kitchen) that you can tap into for the closet outlet?

There may be exceptions to the "kitchen branch circuit" restriction in the code that I'm not aware of that would allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Kitchen countertop receptacle circuits cannot be used for anything except receps in kitchen and dining area, and oven exhaust fan, and clock.  They're rather specific on that point.   "But it's grandfathered" in that case you're still not allowed to make it *worse*.

Comment: There is a Hall way light and an outlet in the hall that the closet is in.

Comment: There will be or should be a continuous hot feed in either the hall switch or the hall light fixture if either of these make it easier to get access. The outlet certainly will be hot all the time but it's lower on the wall, so it may make it more difficult because of it.

Comment: Could I come off the light switch and then to the outlet in the closet?

Comment: Sure.  Just make sure you come off the unswitched (hot) side of the switch.